# Do removed posts impact reputation immediately?

Tags: support, bug, reputation

My reputation just dropped by 40 pts, which sort of surprised me. So I checked the [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet?tab=reputation) tab and there is nothing there to explain the drop.

[image]

I am showing removed posts and there are no removed posts for today. I went to recalc my rep and it calculates at 13097 (which is the value after the drop).

My rep tab does show that posts were removed on July 7, July 5 and June 30 but those posts do not total to 40. The strange thing is, I know my rep did not drop those days it shows the posts were removed.

[image]

When posts are removed does the rep drop immediately? If there is a time lapse, can that be corrected?  It is confusing to figure out why reputation has dropped if it isn't associated with the day the posts are removed.

Comment: No, the effect is not *immediate*. It can take up to 5 minutes after a post is deleted for it to affect your reputation. However, once your reputation does change, the event *will* appear in your history (there's not an additional waiting time). It may be something else other than a deleted post. You'd have to wait for a moderator.

Comment: It's....pretty fast. Do you have "show removed posts" checked in the rep page? It's at the bottom of the page

Comment: @BenBrocka yes I have show removed posts checked in the rep page

Comment: @animuson there is nothing showing under today as to why my rep dropped.

Answer (score 1):

The date listed is actually the date of the original addition of rep (up-vote, etc.).

The removal note in the reputation history does not indicate *when* something was removed, rather it shows the date *from which* something was removed.